# Laravel 8 axios get - Unathorized

Tags: laravel, axios

I have this simple return function in laravel 8 using axios but I keep getting this error
[image]

**api.php**

```
Route::apiResources([
'user' => 'API\UserController'
]);

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});
```

**My vue code**

```
loadUsers() {
  axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => {
    this.users = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
},
```

**UserController(API)**

```
public function index()
{
    return ['message' => 'Success'];
    //return User::latest()->paginate(5);
}
```

I can't even get into the controller to return the message. I just keep getting the said error in the picture. Did I miss something to set-up?. I already install axios via npm

> Update
> [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUXhGw4aQtA&list=PLB4AdipoHpxaHDLIaMdtro1eXnQtl_UvE&index=15) of the tutorial I watch.

Comment: What kind of authentication do you use for your API ? A Bearer token ?

Comment: @Takachi sorry im just starting to learn a laravel and following a tutorial on youtube. The way i create the api controller is this `php artisan make:controller API/UserController --api`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you're using Bearer token, you have to add the token in your axios request. The following code will do the job :

```
axios.get('api/user', this, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourToken,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

Another point is that you have to pass the Laravel route to the vue component, because **api/user** is not your Laravel route. Here's a [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) about passing data from parent to child vue component.

If you're not using any auth methods, just remove the middleware from your api.php file :

```
Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: I provide the link of the tutorial. He didn't use any token. so I don't know where to get the token param

Comment: Can you show us your api.php route file ?

Comment: Edited. That's all the code in my api.php

Comment: Your route is using an auth middleware, remove it for testing like that ```Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});```

Comment: It's working but it's not returning anything. It returns blank

Comment: Edited my answer, you just have to import the UserController class into your api.php file. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228310/discussion-between-takachi-and-kira).